# Why is this class not found?

Tags: scala, inner-classes

In a scala program I've created a case to match a user, following some snippets from **http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html**

In particular, I have declared a class extending another class, and then I've attempted to case match against that class.

```
user match {
  case FreeUser(name) => "Hello " + name;
  case PremiumUser(name) => "hello " + name;
}
```

These operations both fail: it seems as though the case clause doesn't see the class definitions for the FreeUser and PremiumUser classes, which are immediately above it.

```
class FreeUser(val name: String) extends User{
  def unapply(user: FreeUser):Option[String] = Some(user.name);
}

//takes the object as input, returns the parameter used to construct it.
class PremiumUser(val name: String) extends User {
  def unapply(user: PremiumUser):Option[String]= Some(user.name);
}
val name = "ASDF"
val user: User = new PremiumUser("jay");
user match {
  /** This statement fails to comiple : not found, value FreeUser. **/
  case FreeUser(name) => "Hello " + name;
  case PremiumUser(name) => "hello " + name;
}
```

For the full class, you can reference this gist.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e96107f91ef0262f3268

My question is, thus, simply how to reference an inner class in a case clause in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unapply method must be defined in the companion object:

```
object FreeUser {
  def unapply(user: FreeUser):Option[String] = Some(user.name);
}

object PremiumUser {
  def unapply(user: PremiumUser):Option[String]= Some(user.name);
}
```

I can't find at the moment something official about why you can't have unapply in classes, I think it's because matching on classes implicitly calls `SomeObject.unapply` and to do so it can't be a class (you'll have to do `new SomeClass.unapply`, with a singleton is much better).

Comment: This is exactly my question - is why the method cant be in the class, but for now , this solves my problem by clarifying that for some reason, the companion object implementations of the unapply method are what are used.. thanks!

Comment: Consider your example, you have a class which takes a string as parameter, if the unapply method was defined in the class, how should the compiler be able to call it? It can't istanciate a new class of course and he can't call unapply of the current class being matched because it doesn't know yet its type (i.e. you don't know if you can call the unapply method).

Answer (score 4):

both freeUser and the PreimumUser classes should be case classes as follows;

```
/**
 * Why does FreeUser fail to compile?
 */
object Sytax {

  object Thrice {
       def apply(x : Int) : Int = x *3
       def unapply(z : Int) : Option[Int] = if (z%3==0) Some(z/3) else None
  }

  val x = Thrice(3);

  trait User {
    def name:String;
  }

  case class FreeUser(val name: String) extends User{
    def unapply(user: FreeUser):Option[String] = Some(user.name);
  }

  //takes the object as input, returns the parameter used to construct it.
  case class PremiumUser(val name: String) extends User {
    def unapply(user: PremiumUser):Option[String]= Some(user.name);
  }
  val name = "ASDF"
  val user: User = new PremiumUser("jay");
  user match {
    case FreeUser(name) => "Hello " + name;
    case PremiumUser(name) => "hello " + name;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but not as concise as the former one. :)